# HttpContext is null in a method called inside Parallel.For

Tags: c#, asynchronous, parallel-processing, null, httpcontext

Posting this question after trying a lot. Doing [normal `for` is not an option](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35343865/2404470) because we need to do a large amount of processing in very less time.

I have `GetDataFor()` inside which `HttpContext.Current` is used.

The code looks like this:

```
public void SomeMethod()
{
    var context = HttpContext.Current;

    Parallel.For(0, 100, i =>
    {
        var data = GetDataFor(i, context);
    });
}

public data GetDataFor(int i, HttpContext context)
{
    Uri requestUri = null;
    if (HttpContext.Current != null)
    {
        requestUri = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url;
        sCookie = string.Format("{0}", HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["cookie"]);
    }
    else
    {
        requestUri = context.Request.Url;
    }

    //do something
    return data;
}
```

Everything works fine inside normal `for` loop. However, when I call it inside [`Parallel.For`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460713%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and pass `HttpContext.Current`, `HttpContext.Current.Request`, `HttpContext.Current.Request.Url` as [method parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16438740/2404470):

> HttpContext.Current cannot be serialized because it does not have a parameterless constructor

[Passing `HttpContextBase httpContext = null` as parameter throws](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3790942/2404470):

> To be XML serializable, types which inherit from ICollection must have an implementation of Add(System.Object) at all levels of their inheritance hierarchy. System.Web.HttpApplicationStateBase does not implement Add(System.Object).

Tried making a property:

```
public string[] httpContextData
{
    get
    {
        string requestUrl = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString();
        string sCookie = string.Format("{0}", HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["cookie"]);
        return new string[] { requestUrl, sCookie };
    }
}
```

and using in method:

```
var contextData = httpContextData;
```

which throws:

> System.Uri cannot be serialized because it does not have a parameterless constructor

I did all this to send it's [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8109526/the-cross-thread-usage-of-httpcontext-current-property-and-related-things#comment58652454_12219078) and [state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7851532/c-anything-wrong-with-setting-httpcontext-current-in-a-parallel-thread#comment58653226_7851532) but unable to understand why the problem is not solving.

How do I use `HttpContext.Current` inside `Parallel.For`? What am I doing wrong here?

Btw, the needed stuff are:

`HttpContext.Current.Request.Url` and `HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["cookie"]`

Comment: Is there anyway you can show your actual code? You've done a good job of explaining what you are doing, but I feel like there must be some key detail your accidentally leaving out. The error you are receiving just doesn't make sense to me given your explanation.

Comment: @MarkRucker Sure I also feel that adding code will help future readers (**myself** included). I hope my recent [update](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/35483658/revisions) is [mcve](stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`HttpContext.Current` is only available (not null) inside *request-handling threads*. `Parallel.For` creates multiple threads, none of which is has access to `HttpContext.Current`.

You have to pass all data that code in `Parallel.For` threads needs either through

- local variables assigned before the loop or
- `TLocal` instance used in `Parallel.For<TLocal>`.

In any event, code such as `HttpContext.Current....` is out.

Comment: So, I shall pass `HttpContext.Current.Request.Url` and `HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["cookie"]` as params? I have tried them :( I'll try [`TLocal`](https://www.google.com/search?q=TLocal) and get back

Comment: I declared `string requestUrl = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString();` and `string sCookie = string.Format("{0}", HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["cookie"]);` and passing them as normal string *and not complex serial objects* did the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The code is proprietary hence I'm only posting the [relevant parts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35343865/2404470):

Since passing the following objects:

- `HttpContext.Current`
- `HttpContext.Current.Request`
- `HttpContext.Current.Request.Url`

  as params to `GetDataFor` was throwing so many errors.

Also, my needs were only

1. request url *which can be re-generated by passing url* as `string` to it's constructor
2. and a request header's value which is essentially a `string`

I only passed `string` to `GetDataFor()` method:

```
public void SomeMethod()
{
    string requestUrl = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString();
    string sCookie = string.Format("{0}", HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["cookie"]);

    Parallel.For(0, 100, i =>
    {
        var data = GetDataFor(i,
    requestUrl: requestUrl,
    sCookie: sCookie);
    });
}

public data GetDataFor(int i, string requestUrl = null, string sCookie = null)
{
    Uri requestUri = null;
    if (HttpContext.Current != null)
    {
        requestUri = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url;
        sCookie = string.Format("{0}", HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["cookie"]);
    }
    else
    {
        requestUri = new Uri(requestUrl);
    }

    //do something
    return data;
}
```

Comment: And the serialization error happened in GetDataFor?

Comment: @MarkRucker The project did compiled well, but when I tried to run, the error was shown as a yellow red ASP.NET stack trace.

Comment: well I'm just not sure. I guess it is just one of those weird bugs. It sounds like you have a working solution, so if it were me I'd just run with that.